# How can a create a DataTable programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

How can I create a DataTable programatically? i have the following code and I was wanting to create a data table just like in Java that would allow me to create a table that I could file with data from a CSV (,) such as names, address, and phone numbers.

Code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      private System.Data.DataSet dataSet;
      System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable("ParentTable");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         private void MakeParentTable()
         {
                    DataColumn column;
                    DataRow row;

                    column = new DataColumn();
                    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                    column.ColumnName = "id";
                    column.ReadOnly = true;
                    column.Unique = true;

                    table.Columns.Add(column);

                    column = new DataColumn();
                    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                    column.ColumnName = "ParentItem";
                    column.AutoIncrement = false;
                    column.Caption = "ParentItem";
                    column.ReadOnly = false;
                    column.Unique = false;

                    table.Columns.Add(column);

                    DataColumn[] PrimaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
                    PrimaryKeyColumns[0] = table.Columns["id"];
                    table.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;

                    dataSet = new DataSet();

                    dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

                    for (int i = 0; i<= 2; i++)
                    {
                        row = table.NewRow();
                        row["id"] = i;
                        row["ParentItem"] = "ParentItem " + i;
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
         }

         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             MakeParentTable();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: MSDN really is a good resource for many things! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zd7cwzh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FileStream and StreamReader for reading data from csv file.  I see that you create DataTable programmaticaly in your code.

Comment: Yes, but the table did not show in my form for some reason.

Comment: Use DataGrid class. Call SetDataBinding(your_dataset, tablename) of the DataGrid . for more info look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I think that C# is much more complex to start with the Java was. In java you can just create a DataTable and it will appear on the  screen but in C# if you create it in the program it does not show up in design view. Its a real misnomer to me, any way.